# JQL Find Blockers of Blockers

Tags: jira, scrum, jql

In my company, we have, amongst others, two link types: `BLOCKS` and `IS BLOCKED BY`.  We also have a status of `IMPEDED`.

Let’s say there are three issues: **Issue A**, **Issue B**, and **Issue C** :

`Issue A` - status is `IMPEDED`, is linked to `Issue B` with a link type of `IS BLOCKED BY`.

`Issue B` - Status is `IMPEDED`, is linked to `Issue A` with a link type `BLOCKS` and is linked to `Issue C` with a link type `IS BLOCKED BY`.

`Issue C` - status is `READY`, has a link to `Issue B` with a link type `BLOCKS`.

So basically, we can’t work on **A** until **B** is finished.  And we can’t work on **B** until **C** is finished.  So we have to finish `issue C` first.

I want to be able to run a JQL query that will return `issue C`.  In other words, I want to find issues that are blockers to issues that block other issues.

This is very similar to a depth first search on a tree.  Problem is that I have no idea how to do that in JQL.

Does anybody have any ideas?

Comment: Do you have Jira on prem or Jira cloud? Any plugins for JQL installed? E.g. ScriptRunner may help with such request

Answer (score 0):

I successfully used such filters to identify tickets that are blockers for other but are not blocked themselves:

```
project=YourProject and status!=READY and issue in linkedIssuesFromQuery("project=YourProject", BLOCKER, inward) and issue not in linkedIssuesFromQuery("project=YourProject and status!=READY", BLOCKER, outward)
```

First part

```
project=YourProject and status!=READY
```

simply finds unresolved tickets.
Next part:

```
issue in linkedIssuesFromQuery("project=YourProject", BLOCKER, inward)
```

filters for tickets being in inward relation of type BLOCKER so the ones that block other tickets.

Finally last part:

```
issue not in linkedIssuesFromQuery("project=YourProject and status!=READY", BLOCKER, outward)
```

filters for tickets not being blocked by unresolved (not READY) tickets (outward relation BLOCKER).